# Assign Values of a column in SubQuery in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to do following in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCER_NAME, PRODUCER_ID,
    (SELECT @X = @X + PRODUCT_NAME 
     FROM PRODUCT 
     WHERE PRODUCER_ID = PRODUCER.ID) 
FROM 
    PRODUCER
```

There are two tables. `Producer` table is list of all producers. `Product` table stores product produced by producers. `@x` is `varchar` variable

Basically I want a list of all products, comma-separated by producer.

For example

```
Producer     Products
--------     --------------------------
P1           ProductA,ProductB,ProductC
P2           ProductD,ProductE
```

I don't know if this is possible this way. Do anyone know how to do this without joining tables?

Comment: That's where I was confused, So I asked question like that....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a way for you to assign multiple output comma-separated lists to a single varchar variable, but maybe you don't actually need that anyway. Try this:

```
SELECT Producer = PRODUCER.PRODUCER_NAME, 
       Products = STUFF(
       (
         SELECT N',' + PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME 
           FROM dbo.PRODUCT
           WHERE PRODUCT.PRODUCER_ID = PRODUCER.ID 
         FOR XML PATH(''), 
         TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'')
  FROM dbo.PRODUCER;
```

On a large table, this kind of correlated subquery can be quite expensive. On SQL Server 2017+ we can use `STRING_AGG()` in a single pass:

```
SELECT Producer = PRODUCER.PRODUCER_NAME, 
       Products = STRING_AGG(PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME, N',')
FROM dbo.PRODUCT
INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUCER
  ON PRODUCT.PRODUCER_ID = PRODUCER.ID
GROUP BY PRODUCER.PRODUCER_NAME;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16024e5cc430b7a2d5ecf195e2208a9d)

Comment: Aaron I tried your code and it works very well but it takes time to fetch the results. Could it be because of indexing?

Comment: @Jignesh yes, it could be. Is there an index on `PRODUCT.PRODUCER_ID`? How many rows are we talking about here? And how long is "time"?

Comment: not sure who downvoted this but ... oh well. nevermind. i'll assume it was revenge

Comment: There is an index on combined primary key PRODUCER_ID, PRODUCT_ID AND there are 5 producers and one PRODUCER_ID has 300 products on average. It took 3 seconds to fetch.

Comment: @Jignesh well, you could also consider performing a normal join and then performing the concatenation on the client. It may very well be faster at that than SQL Server.

Comment: @Aaron Actually I used Product just as an example as I cannot reveal actual database structure. Even with 5 producers with 300 products , it takes more the the join time, I think the reason being it scans entire product table every time(i.e. for every producer), while in case of join, it scans only once.

Comment: Well it does make a difference, and I think that OP troubles with execution could be part of bad formatting and not using aliases in the corelated query. Suppose that product doesn't have PRODUCER_ID column at all. What will you receive as the result? That's why I suggest always use the table aliases. Also this query will incorrectly work with names like 'Product & 1', that's why in my answer I've used value and not implicit conversion. So even if OP was able to use your answer, I really don't want others to do so, because this could lead to hidden bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate names, you can do this:

```
select
    P.PRODUCER_NAME, P.PRODUCER_ID,
    stuff(
        (
            select ',' + T.PRODUCT_NAME
            from PRODUCT as T
            where T.PRODUCER_ID = P.PRODUCER_ID
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 1, '') as PRODUCT_NAMES
from PRODUCER as P
```

Two notes:

1. Always use the table aliases for such a queries. To see why - delete alias name from query and drop PRODuCER_ID from PRODUCT table.
2. Use `value` method instead of implicit conversion to nvarchar to correctly work with names like 'Product & 1'.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and notes!!! Those work great!!! an By the way in my question, table names and column names are  all not real.

Comment: Yeah, I see, the only point was to warn people to use aliases

Comment: For now, I could not use any of them unfortunately as the table being so big, It is taking more time than joining the two tables.

Comment: you could try to use cursor solution for that